# how to make an async function complete before moving to the next task in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

I have a function (nodejs on aws Lambda) that reads all the files in a directory on s3, converting each, and merging their contents before returning to the front end.

The main function is as follows:

```js
export async function handleFilesRequest(foundry: string, type: string): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {


  let accumulatingMap: Map<string, any> = new Map<string, any>();
  try {
    accumulatingMap = await getFileList(foundry, type)
      .then((list) => {
        return list.map(async key => {
          readFile(key)
            .then(content => {
              return transformFile(content)
            })
            .then((currMap) => {
              accumulatingMap = new Map<string, any>([...accumulatingMap.entries(), ...currMap.entries()])
              return accumulatingMap;

            })
            .then((acc) => {
              // a console.log here shows that this has the complete set of values (but not in time, I guess)
              return accumulatingMap;
            })
        })

      }).catch(e => {
        return new Map<string, any>();
      }) as Map<string, any>;

    return OK.format(JSON.stringify(accumulatingMap));

  } catch (e) {
    return ServerError.format(e);
  }
}
```

What happens is that the variable `accumulatingMap` has not had time to get its values before it is returned in the line:

```
return OK.format(JSON.stringify(accumulatingMap));
```

how do I ensure that accumulatingMap has the time to complete, or is completed, before that return line is called?

I have tried variations of Promise.all and Promise.resolve, but these just seem to wrap things in further Promise's and don't actually halt the process in time for the Values to complete. Or, at least, it didn't seem to work for me.

how do I make this work?

BTW: the statement from MDN web docs (The await operator is used to wait for a Promise and get its fulfillment value.) does not seem to to work, so a sub-question is: what is `await` really for?

The functions that this function delegates to all appear to work (doing as I expect them to do), so I have listed them here as a reference:

```
const readFile = async (key: string): Promise<string> => {

  if (key?.endsWith('.json')) {

    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: key,
    });
    return s3Client.send(command).then(b => {
      return b.Body?.transformToString() as Promise<string>;
    });

  }
  return ''
}

const transformFile = (content: string): Map<string, any> => {
  let objFileContents = JSON.parse(content);
  let fileResult: Map<string, any> = new Map<string, any>();

  if (objFileContents) {
    (Object.keys(objFileContents)).forEach(k => {
      fileResult.set(objFileContents[k].name, objFileContents[k])
      return fileResult;
    })

  }
  return fileResult;
}

const getFileList = async (foundry: string, type: string): Promise<string[]> => {
  const command = new ListObjectsCommand({
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: `resources/${foundry}/`
  });

  const listedObjects = [];
  const data: ListObjectsCommandOutput = await s3Client.send(command);
  if (data['Contents'] && data['Contents'].length > 0) {
    for (let index = 0; index < data['Contents'].length; index++) {

      let currentKey = data['Contents'][index]['Key'];

      if (currentKey?.includes(type)) {
        listedObjects.push(currentKey);
      }
    }
  }

  return listedObjects;

}
```

Comment: You are using await .then which I have never even seen. When you use await you don't use .then. I think that's the problem.

Comment: ok...so how do i build up a map and then return the overall result? I need the various thens because I'm making calls and composing the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mixed usage of `await` and `.then` is absolutely an anti-pattern, and almost definitely causing the code to behave differently to how you expect.

I've rewritten the code to just use `await`, and to have a more direct structure:

```
export async function handleFilesRequest(foundry: string, type: string): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
  try {
    const fileList = await getFileList(foundry, type);
  
    const fileMaps = await Promise.all(fileList.map(async (key) => {
      try {
        const content = await readFile(key);
        return transformFile(content);
      }
      catch {
        return new Map<string, any>();
      }
    }));

    const entries = fileMaps.flatMap((item) => [...item.entries()]);
    const accumulatingMap = new Map<string, any>(entries);

    return OK.format(JSON.stringify(accumulatingMap));
  }
  catch (e) {
    return ServerError.format(e);
  }
}
```

In general, there's a few issues with your original code:

- You call `.then` on things that don't return promises (e.g. `transformFile`)
- You call `.then` on something you've already `await`ed, which doesn't work the way you expect
- You don't await the promises in your map

I'd highly recommend reading more about the difference between async/await and the traditional .then promise API; as the control flow is quite different between the two of them.

Comment: Yep. OK. this worked. Thank you so much ...and you're quite right, i don't understand what I'm doing. Do you recommend any documentation?...as pretty much all the references I've read are...well...terse, or go though only the simplest of cases.

Comment: BTW: there's yet another issue in my code: I cant `JSON.stringify(accumulatingMap)` Maps don't stringify and maps of objects don't stringify. I'm going to have to write my own stringifier - thankfully that won't be async.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't wait for promises in Array::map, map returns an array, not a promise. The second issue is that you don't return `readFile(key)` promise from the map.

try to update your code with this:

```js
accumulatingMap = await getFileList(foundry, type)
  .then((list) => {
    return Promise.all(list.map(async key => {
      return readFile(key)
        .then(content => {
          return transformFile(content)
        })
        .then((currMap) => {
          accumulatingMap = new Map<string, any>([...accumulatingMap.entries(), ...currMap.entries()])
          return accumulatingMap;

        })
        .then((acc) => {
          // a console.log here shows that this has the complete set of values (but not in time, I guess)
          return accumulatingMap;
        })
    })
```

**EDIT**: just realized that the code has a race condition. This is a fixed code:

```js
accumulatingMap = await getFileList(foundry, type)
  .then((list) => {
    return Promise.all(list.map(async key => {
      return readFile(key).then(content => {
          return transformFile(content)
      })
    }).then(maps => {
       // Here you have an array of transformed files
       // and you can convert that to Map object.
       // The output Map will be the result of the promise and
       // await expression
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't quite work, but it may have brought me closer. There seems to be consistently more in the accumulatingMap at the end (although not enough that the lambda itself returns anything)

Comment: Actually, I understand an extra thing now. I originally tried wrapping the whole lot in a promise.all. I can see that you have to be using it in "promise land", not on the outside, where you are expecting the resolved values.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I'm not sure if this is what you expect but `accumulatingMap` will be an array of Maps objects. If you want to have a single Map you need to use an async reduce function or first process the files and then create an Map object. Also, you have a race condition. Just realized this. I can update the code

Comment: prior to your edit, a single map was returned (the merged result of all files), which was what was desired. So, yes processing the files (which are themselves maps), then merging them is the better option. Did you see the response by @Toastrackenigma? they mention the problems of mixing await and .then

Comment: @MichaelCoxon yes I've seen it, I first commented edited and then found the accepted answer.